# Design bug in chat when you click on a user's picture?

Tags: bug, chat, design

I was in chat and clicked on a user's image to see the stuff under his name. This is what I saw:

[image]

At the very top is where I enter the URL. At the very bottom is where I enter the chat message. You can see that there is so much stuff in this user's chat "profile" that it overflows to the top. Scrolling does not revel it. It stays fixed on the page. I suggest that such instances keep the "profile" height at what ever the window's height is and overflows the rest. Or perhaps it can be absolutely positioned instead of fixed<sup>1</sup>.

---

1. Fiddling in the developer tools, I fixed it by changing `position:fixed` to `position:absolute` on `.popup` class and added `position:relative` to `body` in the css. Needs some work on the z-index though because it ends up on top of the area where you enter messages (`#input-area`).

Comment: @TimStone Yes, so it seems. Over a year past now and it seems like such an easy fix, though I admit the developer tools sometimes lie.